# JCR OAK Query & NodeType

Tags: lucene, jcr, jackrabbit

I am working on Apache JackRabbit OAK (1.3.2).
I have created a node (MyNode) with the following structure and saved in the repository.

 -- 'jcr:primaryType'=oak:Unstructured 

 -- 'name'='myNode'

I also created a lucene index to index all the properties as per the [documentation](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/query/lucene.html).
However when i run the following query i get no results.

`select * from [oak:Unstructured] where name='myNode'`

And when the run the following query i get the saved 'MyNode' in result

 'select * from [nt:base] where [jcr:primaryType]='oak:Unstructured' and name='myNode''

1. Why am i not able to query with [oak:Unstructured], when this is declared nodeType
2. How do i verify if i am able to leverage the lucene index created?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Why am i not able to query with [oak:Unstructured], when this is declared nodeType

The reason I was not able to query was during the creation of the node, just setting the property 'jcr:primaryType' to 'oak:Unstructured' is not enough. We need to set the type of this property to "NAME" explicitly, else it will be treated as a "STRING" property.

> How do i verify if i am able to leverage the lucene index created?

Just creating the index node will not satisfy for indexing, we also need to initialize the repository with indexing. I used the following line to enable indexing in my repository.

```
      jcr.withAsyncIndexing();
```