# Jackrabbit OAK property index never used

Tags: jackrabbit

I am trying to use property index with Jackrabbit but when i have many thousands of nodes it seems that transversal mode is always chosen for query execution.

For example, i have 10 000 nodes of type `test:mytype` under a single node `/mystore`. Into each of these nodes i have a property `test:myprop` with 3 different possible values (nearly 3000 nodes for each value).

When i run the following query

```
select [jcr:uuid] from [test:mytype] where [test:myprop]='MyValue'
```

then query engine processor always use the transversing mode and do not use the index i have created for `test:myprop`.

I tried to debug the code directly, i clearly see the query engine trying to use the property index i have defined but do not use it because cost of transversing cursor index seems to be always "100" and my property index contains nearly "3000" nodes for each possible value. Query engine consider that using transversal cursor will be more efficient, even if engine will need to transverse 10000 nodes.

Did someone already faced similar problem ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Oak 1.3.x, you will have to initialize the indexing while repository creating the repository. Pls refer to my answer on this [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32457605/jcr-oak-query-nodetype).

Post this you will have to create the [indexes](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/query/lucene.html) manually for Oak to index them and use in query.